# es recomendable pasar muchos parametros

Tags: c#, método, buenas-prácticas

Cordial saludo.
Estoy realizando una aplicacion en c# usan la programa en tres capas pero tengo la duda de que si es recomendable pasar muchos parámetros a un método, si no es así, ¿que puedo hacer?,¿hay algún patrón de diseño para solucionar esto?, ejemplo:

```
Public void Registrar(String Nombre, String Apellido, int Edad, 
                      Datetime fechaNacimiento,String Correo, 
                      String Direccion, char sexo){

}
```

Comment: No sería mejor crear una clase llamada `Persona` y definir como campos `nombre`, `apellido`, `edad`, etc?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo había pensado pero si adicional a la información de la persona también quisiera pasar mas información no relacionado con una persona.

Comment: Podrías crear otra clase (o struct, enumeración, etc; dependiendo de lo que necesites) que se relacione con la clase `Persona`

Comment: si 8 parametros te parecen mucho, no viste muchas de las clases de .net....

Comment: lo ideal como dice Xam es crear la clase Persona y luego en el método Registrar le pasas como parámetro la Clase Persona.

Comment: Si quieres pasar mas informacion de la persona, envias el objeto `Persona` y la informacion adicional en `params`.
Algo asi: `public void Registrar(Persona persona, params object[] infoAdicional)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// declaras una clase con tus parámetros
public class EnParametro
{
    public String Nombre  { get; set; }
    public String Apellido  { get; set; }
    public int Edad  { get; set; }
    public Datetime fechaNacimiento  { get; set; }
    public String Correo  { get; set; }
    public String Direccion  { get; set; }
    public char sexo  { get; set; }
}


// creas un método que usa la clase y asignas valores

public void cargar(){

EnParametro parametros = new EnParametro();
parametros.Nombre = "juan";

// envias los paramtros a tu metodo Registrar. y listoo.
Registrar(parametros);
}


public void Registrar(EnParametro parametros)
{
   string nombre = parametros.Nombre;
}
```